# eclipse.exe disappeared after un-installing developer tools

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I was trying to update developer tools from 22 to 23.xx. I was not able to proceed and was trying to uninstall existing developer tools version 22.x.x and then install 23.x. But after the un-installation eclipse.exe disappeared.

Comment: The Android SDK tools doesn't delete exe files. Sounds like you accidentally pressed the delete key. Check the recycle bin

Comment: I checked. unfortunately it is not found in recycle bin.

Comment: Well, if you can't find it in the folder you downloaded eclipse to, then you'll need to re-download eclipse. Or this a sign that you should finally migrate to Android Studio after 3 months of eclipse not being supported anymore

Comment: Thank you! I have to keep eclipse to do some pydev projects.But some irritating popup was coming everytime i open eclipse sayin `"Android SDK requires android developer toolkit version 23.0 or above" `

Comment: Then you can just use Intellij with the Python Community and Android plugins.